# how to add number in every moves in tower of hanoi

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

```
def hanoi(disks, source, Destination, auxiliary):
    if disks == 1:
        print('move disk 1 from tower {} to tower {}.'.format(source, auxiliary))
        return
    hanoi(disks - 1, source, auxiliary, Destination)
    print('move disk {} from tower {} to tower {}.'.format(disk, source, auxiliary))
    hanoi(disks - 1, Destination, source, auxiliary)
disk = int(input('Input Disk: '))
hanoi(disk, 'A', 'B', 'C')

n = disk
d =(2**n)-1
print("\nTotal Moves " + str(d))
```

I need to add number 1-10000 as in the image depend on how many moves execute. Can anyone give me a hint?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an additional argument, a counter:

```
def hanoi(disks, source, Destination, auxiliary, cnt=1): # initial counter = 1
    if disks == 1:
        print('{}. move disk 1 from tower {} to tower {}.'.format(cnt, source, auxiliary))
        return cnt + 1 # increment counter after move and return
    cnt = hanoi(disks - 1, source, auxiliary, Destination, cnt)
    print('{}. move disk {} from tower {} to tower {}.'.format(cnt, disk, source, auxiliary))
    return hanoi(disks - 1, Destination, source, auxiliary, cnt + 1) # increment counter after move and return the result of the next hanoi call


disk = int(input('Input Disk: '))
total = hanoi(disk, 'A', 'B', 'C') # you can take the total number of move as return from hanoi


n = disk
d = (2 ** n) - 1
print("\nTotal Moves " + str(d))
print(f"Total Moves (returned total from `hanoi`) {total-1}")  # another way to print the total number of moves
```

Output:

```
Input Disk: 3
1. move disk 1 from tower A to tower C.
2. move disk 3 from tower A to tower B.
3. move disk 1 from tower C to tower B.
4. move disk 3 from tower A to tower C.
5. move disk 1 from tower B to tower A.
6. move disk 3 from tower B to tower C.
7. move disk 1 from tower A to tower C.

Total Moves 7
Total Moves (returned total from `hanoi`) 7
```